# How to open a new file in gvim? E303: Unable to open swap file

Tags: windows, vim, gvim

I use gvim on Windows. How can I open a new file?

I have tried with `:e ~\mypath\myfile.txt` but I get this error message:

> E303: Unable to open swap file for "C:\Users\Jonas\mypath\myfile.txt", recovery impossible

How to open a new file using gvim on Windows?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Solution 1

This seem to be a bug. From [Vim E303: Unable to open swap file for "[No Name]", recovery impossible](http://languor.us/vim-e303-unable-open-swap-file-no-name-recovery-impossible), I should add this to `_gvimrc`:

```
set directory=.,$TEMP
```

## Solution 2

To clarify the location of files and directories, which aren't immediately obvious, here is another solution.

Make the following directories (e.g., from a command prompt):

```
mkdir %HOMEPATH%\vim\backup
mkdir %HOMEPATH%\vim\tmp
```

Note that `%HOMEPATH%` equals `C:\Users\User.Name`, where "User.Name" is your Windows user name.

Then copy the following into `%HOMEPATH%\_vimrc`:

```
set backup
set backupdir=$HOME\vim\backup
set directory=$HOME\vim\tmp
set nosmartindent
set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set expandtab
set ai
set pastetoggle=<F2>
syntax on
```

Save the file and the error should go away.

Comment: Thanks! Using the environmental variable `TEMP` seems the best way to go, yet so few people suggest it from what I've seen.

Comment: Note that the second solution has side effects: it set formatting and indentation behaviour, syntax highlighting, and will always make a backup when you write a file.